# Connecting HighCharts with external SQL Server database in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sql-server, highcharts, sharepoint-2013

We have a SharePoint 2013 installation and a SQL Server 2012 with a external database.

We are rendering the information from the SQL Server using HighCharts.

We have been doing this using external lists, creating a BDC connection in order to retrieve the information with CSOM queries to this external list.

Are there any guidelines or best practice for doing this developing a data access layer over the SharePoint?

Comment: So your problem is not connected with Highcharts, but with sharePoint, right?

Comment: We had already developed our charts with Highcharts and connecting to the database server using a SharePoint External List but we want to provide the data to the client side using a web service in order to avoid the creation of a TCE every time and improve the time of response.